# flexbox table, all divs aligned but one, the borders don't match, don't know why

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm doing this table using flexbox, every border matches, but as you see in the fiddle, the second table, the cell with the text: `RIGHT SIDE NOT ALIGNED` has the border which is not perfectly aligned with the border of the row below!

https://jsfiddle.net/buwgq14a/39/

Tried everything, going crazy, any solution? I did the exact same thing as for the upper table, and there it works without problems, no idea what changes between the 2 tables..

thank you

Comment: May I ask why you're not using a `<table>`?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Paulie_D ok got it sorry, but in this case where the code is so long, what should I put in a snipped?

Comment: I didn't use tables because I find that using flexbox allows you for more customization, or at least, I got used to it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you give width as 10% and give 1 px for a div , the width is equivalent to 10% + 1px.

You can give box-sizing property , so that width remains 10% always,

In your code for class, add box sizing property

```
  .epMachinesContentCells2{
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tought about that, but I already get 'box-sizing: border-box;' with bootstrap! Tried anyway to add it directly to that class, but nothing changes!

Comment: and even if I remove that 1px border, that is simply dividing the 2 divs, nothing changes, the borders still don't match the row above